# Maps of profinite sets

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, profinite-groups

I was trying to prove (or disprove) whether or not all maps between profinite spaces are continuous.

One proof in favor was the following. Suppose we have a map of profinite sets $X\to Y$. For any finite quotient $Y\to\tilde{Y}$, the composition $X\to\tilde{Y}$ is continous, as maps to finite sets always are.

To elaborate, the map $X\to\tilde{Y}$ factors through $X\to X/\sim$. Here we have $x_1\sim x_2$ if they have the same image. Then $X/\sim$ is finite, hence discrete (as $X$ is totally disconnected). As a result, $X\to\tilde{Y}$ is continuous.

As a result, the map $X\to Y$ must be continuous, as $Y$ is obtained by taking the inverse limit of the system of the finite quotients. This concludes the proof in favor.

A proof against the statement is the following. Consider the set $X=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ with its usual order topology. This is profinite. However, consider the map $f:X\to X$, where $f(x)=x$ if $x\in\mathbb{N}$, and $f(\infty)=0$. If $f$ where continuous, its image would be compact. However, its image is $\mathbb{N}$, which is not compact.

So my question is, what goes wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please write down what is your definition of "map of profinite sets"? I have never seen it before. Anyway, I suggest you to check whether your map $f$ in the example satisfies this definition.

Comment: It is just aan map of the underlying sets.

Comment: Your $X=\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ isn’t a homogeneous space, so it can’t be a profinite group.

Comment: I am talKing about profinite sets: sets that are compact, Hausdorff and totally disconnected. They don't have to have a group structure.

Comment: @Mar In that case, it is false that "maps to finite sets are always continuous".

Comment: Let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set, which is even a profinite group, and let $E$ be the set of endpoints of the deleted open intervals. Let $f:C\to\{0,1\}$ send every point of $E$ to $0$ and every other point of $C$ to $1$; $f$ is obviously not continuous, since $E$ and $C\setminus E$ are both dense in $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will now take a closer look on that part.